# Time series daily data modeling

Tags: r, time-series

I am looking to forecast my time series. I have the following period daily data 2021-Jan-1 to 2022-Jul-1.
So I have a column of observations for each day.
what I tried so far:

```
d1=zoo(data, seq(from = as.Date("2021-01-01"), to = as.Date("2022-07-01"), by = 1))
tsdata <- ts(d1, frequency = 365)
ddata <- decompose(tsdata, "multiplicative")
```

I get following error here:

> Error in decompose(tsdata, "multiplicative") :
> time series has no or less than 2 periods

From what i have read it seems like because I do not have two full years? is that correct? I have tried doing it weekly as well:

```
series <- ts(data, frequency = 52, start = c(2021, 1))
```

- getting the same issue.

How do I go about it without having to extend my dataset to two years since I do not have that, and still being able to decompose it?
Plus when I am actually trying to forecast it, it isn't giving me good enough forecast:
[Plot with forecast](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZTHbT.png)

My data somewhat resembles a bell curve during that period. so is there a better fitting timeseries model I can apply instead?

Answer (score 0):

A weekly frequency for daily data should have `frequency = 7`, not `52`.  It's possible that this fix to your code will produce a model with a seasonal term.

I don't think you'll be able to produce a time series model with annual seasonality with less than 2 years of data.

You can either produce a model with only weekly seasonality (I expect this is what most folks would recommend), or if you truly believe in the annual seasonal pattern exhibited in your data, your "forecast" can be a seasonal naive forecast that is simply last year's value for that particular day.  I wouldn't recommend this, because it just seems risky, and I don't really see the same trajectory in your screenshot over 2022 that's apparent in 2021.

Comment: Thank you! one of the issues I am seeing with setting frequency to 7 is that my dates are shown incorrectly like when I plot the time series it goes from 2021 to 2032- which isn't accurate

Comment: and do i then summarize my daily data to weeks, or do I keep it daily?

Comment: The decision on the frequency of your time series should probably come from the application / user.  Do they need daily forecasts or weekly forecasts?  There's isn't a right or wrong answer as far as the math is concerned.

Comment: I think the `start` argument to `ts` can only handle monthly and quarterly frequency.  If you have a daily or weekly time series, you can just leave it blank and maintain a separate vector or column with datetime values.

Answer (score 0):

`decompose` requires two full cycles and that a full cycle represent 1 time unit.  ts class can't use `Date` class anyways.  To use frequency 7 we must use times 1/7th apart such as 1, 1+1/7, 1+2/7, etc. so that 1 cycle (7 days) covers 1 unit.  Then just label the plot appropriately rather than using those times on the X axis.  In the code below use %Y in place of %y if the years start in 19?? and end in 20?? so that `tapply` maintains the order.

```
# test data
set.seed(123)
s <- seq(from = as.Date("2021-01-01"), to = as.Date("2022-07-01"), by = 1)
data <- rnorm(length(s))
tsdata <- ts(data, freq = 7)

ddata <- decompose(tsdata, "multiplicative")

plot(ddata, xaxt = "n")
m <- tapply(time(tsdata), format(s, "%y/%m"), head, 1)
axis(1, m, names(m))
```

[image: screenshot]